# Move multiple elements to different locations with one click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm hoping to get some help with something that I simply can't find the answer to. Here is a link to my Codepen: http://codepen.io/Fern444/pen/WRGZNz

So what I'm trying to do is write a code that will cause each #box element to move to different points at the same time with one button click, and back again with another.

I have gotten to the point where I can move the elements to the same place at the same time, but I'm completely stuck on how to move them to different locations. This is my jquery solution, largely adapted from multiple answers I have found elsewhere:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.home-button').click(function(){
if($('.home-button').hasClass('active')){
    $('#box1, #box2').animate({
        width: "60",
        height: "0",
    }, 1000);
$(this).removeClass('active');
}  
else{
    $('#box1, #box2').animate({
        width: "50", 
        height: "300",
    }, 1000);
$(this).addClass('active');        
 };
```

});
});

Does anyone have any tips for me? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use different animate function for each box and provide different positions. But i see that you are increasing the width & height which I see is incorrect. You would need to change the positions.

A more simpler approach would be using CSS for this.

Check this sample edit from your pen here : 
http://codepen.io/vinit-sarvade/pen/RKgMrP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.home-button').click(function(){
      $('#box1, #box2').toggleClass('active');  
    });
});

#box1.active {
  top: 120px;
}

#box2.active {
  top: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vinit. What a beautifully simple solution! :) Thanks so much for your assistance. I'm still relatively new to this, so its amazing to me how you've taken about 25 lines of code and edited it to 4. I've been able to use your changes to fix up my menu. Once again, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is it the solution you are looking for?

```
  $('#box1').animate({
        width: "50", 
        height: "300",
    }, 1000);
   $('#box2').animate({
        width: "50", 
        height: "200",
    }, 1000);
```

Add this code in your else. An if it doesnt work, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Shubhranshu, I have tried your code as well, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me. Thank you though :)

Comment: Hey Jack, I tried this code on your code pen, and the result is ; the user is on top and the envelope is on bottom. And the gets back to the home icon on again click

Comment: Hi Shubhranshu. Ah okay, I may have had another bit of code active that was working against your's. That's great thanks :)